# ASP.NET expose Web.sitemap as sitemap.xml

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

Does ASP.NET support exposing Web.sitemap as a sitemap.xml for google to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box, but it certainly is possible.

Basically, to tackle this project, you will need to break it down into the following phases.

1. Get ASP.NET to intercept the sitemap.xml request
2. Transpose everything which you have in the site map provider into the XML format.
3. Spit out the XML format.

To get step 1 done, you need to do research on how to do this based on the IIS version you will be hosting in. IIS6 and IIS7 Classic mode will yield different implementation logic for IIS7 Integrated mode... more hoops to go through for the former IIS server configurations.

Once you have a request going through ASP.NET process where you are able to wire up a HTTP handler, or if you are using MVC, a route, then you are able to proceed with pumping out the XML.

First step would be able to transpose the data in your web.sitemap file. To do this, you need to access the SiteMap class. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemap_members(v=VS.85).aspx).

Then lastly, you just need to spit it out. Maybe just use Linq to XML for it... but that is just a pretty straight forward task.

Comment: Thanks. The transformation was easy using XLinq. I don't have control over IIS in my cloud hosting provider though (AppHarbor) but suppose I can just point the search engines to a different file name instead without any issues (also not using MVC).

Comment: Cool Bent. I am not sure about the specifics with AppHarbour, but I would imagine that they would be hosting their stuff in IIS7 Integrated mode. But yeah, that is a good idea to just point them to another directory path instead of the 'standard' sitemap.xml. I forgot about that trick.